# Scala SBT - modifying output to be more informative

Tags: scala, sbt

i would like to change the way SBT for Scala presents informations. Any ideas for modification are wellcome but I am most interested in few thing.

How could be done this?

- Remowe parts of information that does not interest you
- Color certain piece of information for example test errors in red
- Show full error stack trace, asserted object values, place where are differences in compared strings ect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the log level to info by typing `info`